# Secure connection with cfftp - which port?

Tags: coldfusion, ftp

I'm using the Coldfusion cfftp tag to make a secure connection to an FTP server:

```
<cfftp action = "open"
  username = "username"
  connection = "myConnection"
  password = "password"
  fingerprint = "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
  server = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
  secure = "yes">
```

And this connects successfully; I can view and download the files on the ftp server. I'm trying to figure out which port it's connecting to. The documentation says that the cfftp tag connects to port 21 by default, so here it looks like it's connecting into port 21. I can specify port=21 or port=22, and it still works the same, either way.

What I'm finding confusing is when I make the same connection manually, using an ftp client (Bitvise SSH client). In Bitvise, I enter the same server IP address, same username, and same password as I am in the cfftp tag. However, I must enter "22" as the port for it to connect successfully. If I enter "21" as the port, I get a message saying that the connection failed. The text of the failed connection is below:

```
14:13:29.767 Current date: 2018-04-11
14:13:29.767 Bitvise SSH Client 7.29, a fully featured SSH client for Windows.
Copyright (C) 2000-2017 by Bitvise Limited.
14:13:29.767 Visit www.bitvise.com for latest information about our SSH software.
14:13:29.767 Run 'BvSsh -help' to learn about supported command-line parameters.
14:13:29.767 Cryptographic provider: Windows CNG (x86) with additions
14:13:29.953 Loading default profile.
14:14:26.599 Started a new SSH2 session.
14:14:26.625 Connecting to SSH2 server xxx.xxx.xx.xx:21.
14:14:47.827 Connecton failed. FlowSocketConnector: Failed to connect to target address. Windows error 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
14:14:47.864 The SSH2 session has been terminated.
```

So I'm not clear on what's happening with the cfftp tag (where I can specify the port as 21 or 22, and it's a successful, secure connection either way), vs. what's happening with the Bitvise client, where the port must be specified as 22 or else the connection fails.

It looks like Bitvise is necessarily trying to establish an SSH2 session. Is that what the cfftp tag is necessarily trying to do, when secure=yes?

Comment: Yes, I suspect the `cfftp` tag is handling the security for you when you specify `secure="yes"`. You could verify this by looking at the network connections from your ColdFusion server while the ftp session is open.

Comment: Port 21 is the default FTP Control port. Port 22 is default SSH. SFTP is a different protocol than FTP, and by default runs over Port 22 (SSH). `cfftp` by default uses a normal FTP connection on Port 21. With a secure flag, it switches to an SSH connection over Port 22. Your server may not be hosting secure traffic over Port 21, which would be why Bitvise fails. Do like Miguel says and look at your traffic. If you can't read your `cfftp` connection, it's SFTP; if you can FTP.

Comment: And note: those are just default, standard ports that everyone uses. You can host HTTP traffic over Port 42 if you want, but any browser that connects to it will try to connect to the default port unless a different one is specified. When you tell Bitvise to connect on 21, you're giving it a non-standard port.

Comment: And final note, your error message indicates you aren't running a Secure FTP connection on Port 21. You may be running a standard FTP server, which allows `cfftp` to connect insecurely (I'm not sure if it falls back from `secure`). If Bitvise is trying to connect over SSH to a port serving FTP, it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, one more note since we're being super-confusing today: There are 2 SFTPs, the first is Simple File Transfer Protocol and is NOT a secure transport method. The other is SSH File Transfer Protocol (which `cfftp secure=true` will use) IS secure. There's also SCP, FTPS, TFTP,........... Lots of ways for a file to go from A to B.

Comment: As you say, any port can be set up for FTP; it doesn't have to be port 21, and any port can be set up for SSH; it doesn't have to be port 22. So, it would make the most sense that cfftp goes to port 21 by default if "secure" is not set to "yes", goes to port 22 by default if "secure" IS set to "yes", and if you explicitly specify a port, it will go to that port. Because, what if the host ftp server did SSH over port 100? I'd need to be able to specify "port=100" in the cfftp tag, and know for sure that it will try to do a SSH File Transfer Protocol connection over port 100.

Comment: So in my test, where I'm specifying "port=21" and "secure=yes", I would expect that it tries to do SSH over port 21, then fails as Bitvise fails when I try to connect through 21. But  in actuality, the cfftp connection is working fine in that situation. So, I'm going to look at the CF server network connections while the connection is open, as suggested and see if that sheds any light...

Comment: ...Spoke too soon. How does one look at the network connections from the CF Server, again? Thought that would be a feature in CF Admin...

Comment: If it's through the CF Admin Server Monitor, can't do it. That only comes with Enterprise, and we have Standard.

Comment: Checking network connections is not a feature of ColdFusion, it is a feature of the operating system. Not sure what you are using but in Windows/Linux the command is `netstat` for example.

Comment: Okay, ran my tests on cfftp with netstat -n, and determined that it is always making the connection to the remote server on port 22, regardless of what port I specify. So most likely, the tag is trying to connect on the port I specified (21), then finds that's not the port for SSH, and then tries port 22 and succeeds. Not sure what's happening to make it check 22; maybe the tag has been programmed to check 22 in that situation because 22 is usually the SSH port, by convention.